# Return data to ajax function data shown in below format

Tags: python, ajax, json

Using jsondump in python I need to send response to ajaxpage

object format in python shell show in below image

how to use the Java server object notation function to send response

//view output data

```
[<Userpost: Userpost object>, <Userpost: Userpost object>]
```

//this is my django view

```
def load_scroll_posts(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    post_id = request.POST['post_id']
 loaded_posts = Userpost.objects.filter(id__gte = post_id)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'up':loaded_posts}))
```

//this is my ajax function

```
function load_remain_user_posts() {
    var post_id = $(".message_box:last").attr("id");
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.post('/theweber.in/load_m',{
    post_id ':post_id,'
    csrfmiddlewaretoken ':csrftoken},   
       function(data){
      //console.log(data)
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj)
      });
        }
```

in console nothing displaying

Comment: Formatting reveals you function has unmatched braces { is this a paste error or you actual code?  Bottom line is that that function with the attempt at "post" is totally improper syntax

Comment: in phasting the code brace was missed see once edited

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean to pass the two variables as parameters to your post?  Something like:

```
function load_remain_user_posts() {
    var post_id = $(".message_box:last").attr("id");
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    var parameters = {
        "post_id": post_id,
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken
    };
    $.post('/theweber.in/load_m', parameters, function (data) {
        //console.log(data)
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj)
    });
}
```